# Java - Using a while loop to solve a calculation

Tags: java, while-loop

using while loop..write a program that when the user inputs 2 integers it computes the result of multiplication of the integers between them and choose i to include the two integers and e to exclude and also the output should be like for example the entered integers are 2,5 it should be like 2*3*4*5=120

Comment: This is not a "we do your homework for you" site.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
int i = 2;
int j = 5;
int ans = 1;
String str = "";

while (i <= j) {

    ans *= i;

    if (i == j)
        str = str + String.valueOf(i);
    else
        str = str + String.valueOf(i) + "*";
    i++;
}

str = str + "=" + String.valueOf(ans);

System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Do not do other people's homework for them. Nobody benefits of you do.